# Renomear um arquivo com um valor de um vetor

Tags: r

estou usando um loop  para extrair centenas de dados usando unzip. No entanto, quero renomear os arquivos com o mesmo nome do arquivo extraído. Estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
zip_postos <- setwd("ZIP_Postos")
zip_postos <- list.files(zip_postos)
postos <- setwd("Postos")
for (i in 1:184){
  unzip(zip_postos[[i]], "CHUVAS.MDB", exdir = postos)
  file.rename("CHUVAS.MDB", paste(zip_postos[[i]]))
}
```

Sei que o código está errado, mas não consigo renomear o arquivo CHUVAS para o nome do arquivo extraído, sem o formato ".zip"

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, basicamente o que você quer fazer é retirar a extensão ".zip" do nome do arquivo. Você pode fazer isso usando o `gsub()`.

Por exemplo, suponha que seu arquivo zip tenho seguinte nome:

```
nome_do_zip <- "arquivo.zip"
```

Então para retirar o zip basta fazer o seguinte:

```
nome_sem_zip <- gsub("\\.zip", "", nome_do_zip)
nome_sem_zip
[1] "arquivo"
```

E aí você pode usar este nome para fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou bastante.